# Can a static IP be shared?

Tags: ip, static-ip

I would like to block a specific business from visiting my website.

I know that they are on a static IP address as a business. When a business is given a static IP address, is this unique to them? I don't want to risk blocking other individuals from the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to know this information. Carrier-grade NAT is very much a thing, and there may be thousands of customers behind a single IP. If you need to restrict access to a website, your best option is to require authentication. There are plenty of ways that this other company could source their  traffic from a different IP, which would get around your IP block. Authentication would still protect your resources , though.

Comment: @EEAA - but wouldn't a static IP assignment be a static assignment or static NAT just for that one customer's edge?  Or are you saying the carriers do something else to allow for multiple customers to have the same "static IP" assignment?  I'm just making sure, because the question was posed as "static IP" and I didn't think a carrier gave out a static IP to multiple customers.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't be  sure that only one company is behind a given IP address. It's quite likely, but not guaranteed.

Blocking the IP is also entirely useless in a time where every member of said company can just get their phone out of the pocket and access the site anyway, and in that case it's quite likely that many hundred users are behind a single IP address.